# Ordinal Logistic regression with factors - help with interpretation

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I've just ran an ordinal logistic regression and I'm having a little trouble interpreting the estimates. The data models attractiveness ratings (likert scale ordinal data) as the DV, with several factorial predictors. The data looks like this (only showing one factor):

| Attractiveness | BMI |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | Emaciated |
| 6 | Underweight |
| 3 | Normal |
| 2 | Overweight |
| 1 | Obese |

The resulting output looks like this:
||Estimate|Std. error|z value |pr(>z)|
| --| --| --| --|--|
|BMIEmaciated |-5.19249 |0.27646|-18.782|< 2e-16 ***|
|BMIObese     |-3.70608|0.27087|-13.682|< 2e-16 ***|
|BMIOverweight  |-1.42338 |0.26141|-5.445|5.18e-08 ***|
|BMIUnderweight |-1.73940|0.26153|-6.651|2.91e-11 ***|

If I take my understanding of how to interpret a simple logistic regression, I know that each of these levels are being compared with BMINormal and that they are log odds. Taking BMI Emaciated, does this mean that when compared with BMINormal there is a 5.19 log odd decrease in scoring higher on the dependent variable (1-7 likert scale)?

However, theory would suggest that Emaciated and Obese would have the lowest overall scores. When I use an inverse logit function on these I get BMIEmaciated: 0.0055274370;  BMIObese: 0.0239843661;   BMIOverweight: 0.1941327100; BMIUnderweight: 0.1493896343, which would represent probabilities. But, these are confusing to me. Does that mean that BMIObese, compared with BMINormal, achieves higher scores on the scale 2% of the time? I'm a bit confused with this interpretation.

I may be overcomplicating this, but any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You're on the right track.   See the first chapter on ordinal regression in [RMS Course Notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms).  **But** your analysis of BMI is completely meaningless.  It is imperative to analyze BMI as a continuous variable. Allow it to act nonlinearity using a regression spline.  Your current approach uses arbitrary BMI boundaries and ignores a lot of heterogeneity within BMI intervals.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it. At present BMI and WHR (waist to hip ratio) are two within-subject factors. They reflect the BMI and WHR of a set of 25 image stimuli presented to participants and each have five levels (WHR: 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0/ BMI: as above), but they are (sadly) not continuous.

Comment: Are you saying that BMI and WHR are control variables, i.e., they can be set to specific constants when generating the data?  If that is the case there is no more continuous information in them and you are OK.